# Taking action on a cancelled Recurring Profile

Tags: event-observer, recurring

Using the default Magento Recurring profiles, is it possible, either through Event/Observer or a cron job to determine which profiles have been cancelled or suspended and take some subsequent action, such as updating a customer group, on those expired/changed profiles?

Comment: I'm not familiar with recurring profiles, but possible is everything. The question is not Is, the question is how much does it cost. The recurring profiles needs to be saved somewhere and there must be an event to hook into.

Comment: Please look at the answers below and mark the one that has helped resolve the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the recurring payments collection, iterate over them and issue requests to the Paypal API to get information about their status:

```
<?php

$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/recurring_profile')->getCollection();

foreach($collection as $profile){
    $profile->fetchUpdate();
    if($profile->hasDataChanges()){
        //display changes, including status
        print_r($profile);
    }
}
```

This eventually makes its way to the `paypal/api_nvp` model which calls `callGetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails` - getting details from the API about the state of the profile.

If you wanted to update Magento with these details, in the `hasDataChanges` if block, call `save` on the profile:

```
$profile->save();
```

Source: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/getrecurringpaymentsprofiledetails-api-operation-nvp

Answer (score 1):

Magento does not implement updating of status of recurring profiles on magento side after updating of status (cancel, reactivate or suspend) on Paypal side. Magento team could did implement it via IPN requests but didn't make it - they implemented only automatic order creation. But status of profile can be updated on magento side manually with "Get Update" button on Profile page in backend or frontend.

When magento is updating status of profile on magento-side it save profile model with new data and dispatch the following event `model_save_after` because `Mage_Sales_Model_Recurring_Profile` extends from `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`.

You can compare `$this->origData('status')` with `$this->getData('status')` from object in observer for knowledge about changing of status after saving of model and compare `$this->getData('status')` with  `Mage_Sales_Model_Recurring_Profile::STATE_SUSPENDED` for knowledge that current status is 'suspended'.

Answer (score 1):

As of Magento **v1.9.1.0**

Copy this file:

`magento/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Recurring/Profile.php`

To here:

`magento/app/code/local/Mage/Payment/Model/Recurring/Profile.php`

Then edit the new copy and add the following after the constant declarations (around line 52):

```
/**
 * Prefix of model events names
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_eventPrefix = 'recurring_profile';
```

Now you can observe the `recurring_profile_save_commit_after` event, and add some  observer code like this:

```
/**
 * Listen to recurring payment profile changes
 * @param   Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return  Custom_Model_Observer
 */
public function processSubscriptionChange($observer)
{

  $data = $observer->getEvent()->getObject()->getData();
  $customer_id = $data['customer_id'];
  $status = $data['state'];
  $sku = $data['order_item_info']['sku'];
  Mage::log('UPDATED RECURRING PAYMENT PROFILE: '.$customer_id. " - ". $sku ." = ".$status, null, 'events.log', true);

  return $this;
}
```